# Netty ServerSocket and Children Graceful Shutdown

Tags: java, server, netty, application-shutdown

I would like to close the server socket on a Netty server and then wait for all children to finish processing before executing resource cleanup.

**Step 1**
Wait for the Netty server socket to close on the main thread using this code where `b` is an instance of `ServerBootstrap`

```
b.bind ( getPort ( p ) ).sync ().channel ().closeFuture ().sync ()
```

**Step 2**
Instruct the server socket to close from a different thread, somewhere else in the application

**Step 3**
Instruct all clients to shutdown, I will have application code that will do this

**Step 4**
Wait for all client sockets to close, **this is what I want to know how to do**. How can I get a list of all client sockets, children of the server, and then wait for all of them to close?

Netty version **4.1.1.Final**

I setup the Netty server socket using the following code snippet

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup ( 1 );
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup ( Math.max ( 1, Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors () / 2 ) );
try
{
  ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap ();
  b.group ( bossGroup, workerGroup )
  .channel ( NioServerSocketChannel.class )
  .childHandler ( new ServerInitializer ( sslctx, jsonIOManager, dispatcherPool, factory ) )
  .childOption ( ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, Boolean.TRUE )
  .childOption ( ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, Boolean.TRUE );

  // wait till server socket is closed    
  b.bind ( getPort ( p ) ).sync ().channel ().closeFuture ().sync ();
  // instruct all clients to shutdown
  dispatcherPool.shutdown ();

  // wait on all sockets that are children of the server socket to close
  // How can i do this?

}
finally
{
  bossGroup.shutdownGracefully ();
  workerGroup.shutdownGracefully ();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [netty 4.x user guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-16) it appears that simply waiting until the `shutdownGracefully` returns will wait until all sockets are closed.

> Shutting down a Netty application is usually as simple as shutting
>   down all EventLoopGroups you created via shutdownGracefully(). It
>   returns a Future that notifies you when the EventLoopGroup has been
>   terminated completely and all Channels that belong to the group have
>   been closed.